# Alignment of views in relative layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I want to align 2 textviews-one on the top left and one on the bottom right. These textviews are placed over the imageswitcher view. I get what I want except that the bottom textview is aligned to the left. I am not able to align it to the right.

Here's the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

    <RelativeLayout   

     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

     <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in"
       />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="140dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="TV 1"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

       <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="140dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="TV2"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove gravity in both textviews. And add align_parent_left and align_parent_top to first textview and align_parent_bottom and align_parent_right to second textview. Try below code:

```
  <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/tv_1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_width="140dp" 
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="TV 1"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

   <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/tv_2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_width="140dp" 
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="TV2"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to the  bottom `TextView`

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

This would be helpful then:)

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="TV 1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_2"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="TV2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
```

Comment: I had added it but it didn't help so I removed it.

Comment: What the problem you faced when you added that attribute??

Comment: I just copied you xml layout and checked with that attribute... It works fine for me

Comment: It didn't align it to the right. It was aligned to the bottom left while the top view was aligned to the top left. I need the bottom one aligned to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but try changing the following to either marginRight or increase dp for marginLeft.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

If you want to give some space between margin and **@+id/tv_2** then you can adjust the below property:

```
android:layout_marginRight="XXdp"
```